# Why are there no software or services that detect Phishing Emails?

Tags: phishing, email-spoofing

I tried Googling, but did not get a definitive answer. I'm looking for software or services that detect Phishing Emails. I read that some software like Norton, Kaspersky, etc. detect phishing websites, but do they detect Phishing Emails? How do you find software or services that detect Phishing Emails? Basically I want a software which can take emails as an input and tell whether an email is phishing or not. If I develop a system (algorithm) to detect phishing emails and test it with a large dataset of emails, I want to compare it with the performance of existing system.

Comment: I'm curious about what you tried to search for that resulted in no hits. There is a growing mass of products and services that help detect phishing. Gmail has a built-in phishing protection function. So does Office 365. Do you mean as a home user with a basic email client?

Comment: All prominent security software with anti-spam features will check against known phishing pattern and its variance.

Comment: You should google "protection from spear phishing". This should give you the result you are looking for.

Comment: @schroeder I'm not so interested in product recommendations. I just want to know whether such softwares EXIST.

Comment: @user5155835 your earlier comments seemed to suggest you wanted products

Comment: yes, they exist in several forms

Comment: @schroeder please can you describe more. More forms means? Please can you give some examples?

Answer (score 2):

Most email services can and do detect malware and often times phishing emails in the form of a Junk Mail service.  There are standalone Exchange based services like McAfee Security for Microsoft Exchange (MSME) that you can custom tune for your environment to detect known phishing site links, etc.

However, you have to understand that anyone can create a simple site that grabs information from people when they enter the site at the drop of a hat.  There is no way to easily detect these "zero day-like" sites that popup constantly.  Your best defense against phishing scams is not so much in the product based solution as it is in the education of those you are trying to protect.  Teach people not to click on suspicious email links.  Disable JavaScript from auto-running on websites.  Disable the ability for people to run executables from websites allowing the system's AV to do it's job better.  Also disable auto-running of anything.

I'm guessing this isn't exactly the answer you were wanting, but unfortunately when it comes to security, this is the most appropriate approach.  But again, nearly all enterprise solutions either already provide some form of this security or you can install products like MSME to help weed out as much as you can.